# How do I align the the height of two sibling inline-blocks relative to each other?

Tags: css

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/czwsK/ how would I align the text "hello" to be 10% of the height of the box from the top? eg the first inline block would be 20px from the top.

Comment: It seems that your demo URL is invalid.

Comment: jsfiddle has been a little wonky the last few days as they've been moving servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/3fpYu/) demonstrates what you need to do. As Diodeus recommends, you shouldn't use a percentage, however if you want to, wrap your elements in a container div and give *that* div the height you want, then you can use percentages with `vertical-align: top` on the text div.

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text">hello</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block; height:100%; width:200px; border: 1px solid black"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
div.container {
    height: 200px;
}

div.text { display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you if want it 20px from the top, you should use 20px, not 10%. Here it is using `%`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="display:inline-block;dislpay:table-cell;vertical-align:top;padding-top:10%">hello</div>
        <div style="display:inline-block; height:200px; width:200px; border: 1px solid black"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```